# How can I add spinner functionality to my ListView items?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a custom list adapter. Here it is:

```
public class FilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PutioFileLayout> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<PutioFileLayout> data = null;

    public FilesAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<PutioFileLayout> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        FileHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new FileHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileListName);
            holder.textDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_fileListDesc);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_fileIcon);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (FileHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        PutioFileLayout file = data.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(file.name);
        holder.textDescription.setText(file.description);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(file.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class FileHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textDescription;
        ImageView imgIcon;
    }
}
```

Pretty short and sweet. I have `Spinner`s in my layout for each row, and I want the user to be able to click them, and get a contextual menu for each item. How can I implement this in my adapter?

My row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="64dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_fileIcon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_fileIcon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_fileListName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="File name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/descriptionFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_fileListDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="File description" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/item_fileSpinner"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_ab_putio" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your row layout xml? Do you have the spinners in there already? If so do they not work? If they don't in what way are they not working. The more you can elaborate about your problem the easier it will be for us to help you.

Comment: Sure thing. Updated question. I don't mean they're "not working", per se.. I just don't know how to make them work in this situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your getView() method get a reference to the spinner like this:

```
Spinner spn = row.findViewById(R.id.item_fileSpinner);
```

once you have the reference you can set its items by creating a [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) with all of your values and set it with

```
spn.setAdapater(mSpinAdapter);
```

I can give you a more specific example of how you'd create and fill your adapter if you can tell me what data you are hoping to fill the spinner with.

then all thats left is to set an [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29), which you can do like this.

```
spn.setOnItemSelectedListner(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int spnPosition, long id){
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Note the use of `spnPosition` in the onItemSelected callback. If you use `position` then you will no longer have access to the getView() parameter `position` so use a different name so that you can access both/either if needbe.

Comment: Great! Will I be able to define the `onItemSelected` in my activity? Or does it have to be done in the adapter?

Comment: you will have to set the onItemSelectedListener inside your adapters getView() method. If you don't need access to any of the getView() parameters in your onItemSelected callback you could create the OnItemSelectedListener object elsewhere within your activity. But you have to set it to the spinner inside the adapter, that is the only place that you get access to the different spinners that will be present in each row of your list.

Comment: Actually I suppose if you want the spinners for every row to do the exact same thing(both the list they contain, and the events that happen when an item is selected) maybe you could try using findViewById() to get a reference to your Spinner in your activity after the ListView has been populated. Then setting the listener from the activity. It might work on every instance of  the spinner but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, this broke my ListView's onItemClick. Also, spnPosition and id always return with the same value (the correct value of id).

Answer (score 2):

why can't you use createContextMenu() ? in case you can, override onContextCreate() and add your view IDs there....

I don't have sample code atm, but I will when i get to the office on monday. Really, context menus are the easiest way to do it.

Then again, tim's idea seems to have did the trick.

EDIT:
as promised on monday, sample code.

res\menu\context_menu.xml   -- note that you can change this name.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_call"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_call"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_video_call"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_video_call"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_send_im"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_send_im"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_call_number"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_call_number"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_view_profile"
    android:title="@string/context_menu_view_profile"/>
```

then in code

```
   @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.listConversations:        //mainContactList from initMainLayoutElements()
            contextList = mainContactList;
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            break;
        case R.id.listContacts:             //chatContacts from initChatLayoutElements()
            contextList = chatContactList;
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            break;
        case R.id.listContactsManagement:       //contactList from initContactLayoutElements()
            contextList = contactMgmtList;
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sms_settings:
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.sms_menu, menu);
            break;
    }
}
```

now that we defined how to open context menus, we need to define what the actual items do...

```
  @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.context_menu_call:
            onCallStartFromContextMenu(false);
            return true;

        case R.id.context_menu_video_call:
            onCallStartFromContextMenu(true);
            return true;

        case R.id.context_menu_send_im:
            layoutState(LayoutState.CHAT);
            Log.d(TAG, "Preparing chat session from context menu for " + getChattersFromList(contextList).toString());
            chatSource = ChatSource.FROM_CONTEXT_MENU;
            prepareChatSessionWith(getChattersFromList(contextList).toArray(new String[getChatterCount(contextList)]));
            return true;

        case R.id.context_menu_call_number:
            Buddy selectedBuddy = (Buddy) contextList.getAdapter().getItem(contextList.getSelectedItemPosition());
            lastCaller = selectedBuddy.toString();
            showAlternateCallDialog(selectedBuddy, !selectedBuddy.getNumberHome().isEmpty(),
                    !selectedBuddy.getNumberMobile().isEmpty(), !selectedBuddy.getNumberOffice().isEmpty());
            return true;

        case R.id.context_menu_view_profile:
            //              Buddy who = buddyAdapter.getItem(listConversations.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Buddy who = (Buddy) contextList.getAdapter().getItem(contextList.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Log.d(TAG, "viewing profile " + who.toString());
            lastProfileName = who.getIdentity();
            showProfileScreen(who);
            return true;
            //transfers

        default:
            contextList = null;
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

don't forget to register the component to the context menu 'listener'. These are actual ListView references.

```
    registerForContextMenu(mainContactList);
    registerForContextMenu(chatContactList);
```

and finally, the only thing left is OPENING the context menus for items...

```
 chatContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "chatContacts.onItemLongClick fired!");
            chatContactList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            openContextMenu(chatContactList);
            return true;
        }
    });

  mainContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "mainContactList.onItemLongClick fired!!!");
            mainContactList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            openContextMenu(mainContactList);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i prefer using context menus on LongClick instead of just onItemClicked because you might wanna do something on clicking (like, file selection and stuff) and offer less-accessed functionalities on a long click like rename / delete etc

so there you go. context menus are easy ;)

Comment: Actually, I think this might be the way to go. Individual spinners are too complicated. Thanks!

Comment: just remember, you need to edit a few files in order to make it work. feel free to email me at darksidemetatron at gmail dot com on monday so i can send you samples.

there's two methods you need to override and add context menu items in a XML file.

Comment: @Shark if you have sample code paste it here so people can use it in the future.

Comment: will do tim, first thing monday. or last, depends on the situation ;)

but yea, i'll post complete code covering a certain use-case.

Comment: Unfortunately, in 3.0 Android changed the Design Document such that long-click should be used for selection, rather than for context menus. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

Comment: Great suggestion. I was trying to add spinners to a ListView, but whenever the ListView redrew its cells, the callback listeners stopped working. I looked at ContextMenu and then settled on PopupMenu, which avoided several problems associated with spinners.